# Google Map API doesn't recenter after resize

Tags: javascript, api

So, I have a map embedded in a hidden div, that when the link is clicked, the division drops down and reveals itself, however, it won't stay centered on the LatLng I've set.  I've read a few articles regarding this and they say you have to initialize the map after displaying the div, but I'm having trouble applying this to my code.  Here's what my current header code looks like.  The class I apply to the link is 'action' and the class of the dropdown division that it's contained in is called 'content'.

http://pastebin.com/wQc6RrSJ

Sorry if I missed anything.
Thanks in advance for the help, Bc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try 2 things:

Fire the resize event of the map:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

If that doesn't work, just call the setCenter method again after resizing the div.

Comment: Well, I have the resize in the jquery, because if I didn't it would produce gray areas on the map and not display properly.  That solved the problem.  How exactly would I add the setCenter method to it?  Here's the jquery that dropsdown the division.

http://pastebin.com/dBuG7kau

Comment: Just call map.setCenter(latLng). latLng can be an array with [lat, lng], or a [LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).
In your code just add google.maps.setCenter([lat, lng]); after the resize event